# jFreechart not display in linux machine

Tags: java, jsp, jfreechart

Jsp

```
<img alt="" src='<%=url+"/chartDemo/servlet/ChartDemoServlet"%>'>
```

I have upper code inside jsp to use jfreechart. I have deployed this application inside tomcat of window machine and its work perfect. But When i copy same file inside tomcat of my linux machine all other content of jsp except chart are displayed.

Why chart are not displayed When i run web application using linux tomcat ?

When i enter servlet directly as URL i found following exception

```
java.lang.Error: Probable fatal error:No fonts found.
    sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1088)
    sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:967)
    sun.font.CompositeFont.doDeferredInitialisation(CompositeFont.java:254)
    sun.font.CompositeFont.getSlotFont(CompositeFont.java:334)
    sun.font.CompositeStrike.getStrikeForSlot(CompositeStrike.java:77)
    sun.font.CompositeStrike.getFontMetrics(CompositeStrike.java:93)
    sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.initMatrixAndMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:358)
    sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.<init>(FontDesignMetrics.java:349)
    sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:301)
    sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.getFontMetrics(SunGraphics2D.java:790)
    org.jfree.text.G2TextMeasurer.getStringWidth(G2TextMeasurer.java:79)
    org.jfree.text.TextUtilities.nextLineBreak(TextUtilities.java:294)
    org.jfree.text.TextUtilities.createTextBlock(TextUtilities.java:235)
    org.jfree.chart.title.TextTitle.arrangeRR(TextTitle.java:628)
    org.jfree.chart.title.TextTitle.arrange(TextTitle.java:497)
    org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart.drawTitle(JFreeChart.java:1316)
    org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart.draw(JFreeChart.java:1204)
    org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart.createBufferedImage(JFreeChart.java:1404)
    org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart.createBufferedImage(JFreeChart.java:1384)
    org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(ChartUtilities.java:183)
    org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(ChartUtilities.java:136)
    com.ChartDemoServlet.doPost(ChartDemoServlet.java:170)
    com.ChartDemoServlet.doGet(ChartDemoServlet.java:64)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: I take it the servlet that generates your chart has been copied as well (or is part of the same project or is available somewhere in your network). Does it work on other mchines? Check what happens to the "url" you append to the "/chartDemoservlet/ChartDemoServlet" path. I don't know how you're setting it but it may depend on server settings (different port used etc.). Try replacing the url with request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort()

Comment: This error is caused by the absence of fonts which are usually installed as part of JRE. Do you use OpenJDK or Oracle? I suggest switching to Oracle for your linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, @Tom is right; look for the used font(s). Earlier on, a Linux without desktop would also have no fonts available (so called headless environment), testable by GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless() and `System.getProperty("java.awt.headless");`. You probably simply can copy the fonts and do a registerFont though.